# Text Area automatically scrolling

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic 3, and have a form with `ion-textarea`'s.

Since I added [fz-elastic](https://github.com/fiznool/ng-elastic), I am however experiencing some strange behaviour. This only happens on a device, and not in a browser.

I have a form with an`ion-input` and two `ion-textarea`'s. If I input a number of rows of data into a `ion-textarea`, and then scroll to the bottom of the page, where I have a submit button, it automatically scrolls back up to the `ion-textarea`, so that I cannot click the button.

I even remove focus from the `ion-textarea` by clicking on a `ion-radio` I have just above the button, but it still just scrolls after a few milliseconds back up to the `ion-textarea`.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Any ideas?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

**jobdetails.html**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Job Details</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <ion-spinner name="dots" *ngIf="loading"></ion-spinner>

    <div *ngIf="jobModel.subCategories && jobModel.subCategories.length > 0" class="category-text animate-show">
      <p class="item-selected-row" *ngFor="let subcategory of getSelected()">
        <img class="item-stable filter-image" id="icon-image-{{subcategory.id}}" src="{{subcategory.icon}}" height="30" width="30" />
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <form [formGroup]="jobdetailsForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Job Title *</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="jobModel.jobTitle" formControlName="jobTitle" id="jobTitle"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <control-messages class="error-box" [control]="jobdetailsForm.controls.jobTitle"></control-messages>
        <span class="char-left" [class.char-left-error]="jobdetailsForm.controls.jobTitle.errors != null" *ngIf="jobModel.jobTitle">{{TITLE_MAX_LENGTH-jobModel.jobTitle.length}} characters left</span>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Job Description *</ion-label>
      <ion-textarea fz-elastic [(ngModel)]="jobModel.jobDescription" formControlName="jobDescription" id="jobDescription"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
    <control-messages class="error-box" [control]="jobdetailsForm.controls.jobDescription"></control-messages>
        <span class="char-left" [class.char-left-error]="jobdetailsForm.controls.jobDescription.errors != null" *ngIf="jobModel.jobDescription">{{DESC_MAX_LENGTH-jobModel.jobDescription.length}} characters left</span>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Further Details</ion-label>
      <ion-textarea fz-elastic [(ngModel)]="jobModel.jobDetails" formControlName="jobDetails" id="jobDetails"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
    <control-messages class="error-box" [control]="jobdetailsForm.controls.jobDetails"></control-messages>
        <span class="char-left" [class.char-left-error]="jobdetailsForm.controls.jobDetails.errors != null" *ngIf="jobModel.jobDetails">{{DETAILS_MAX_LENGTH-jobModel.jobDetails.length}} characters left</span>

    <br>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Drivers Licence</ion-label>
        <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="jobModel.driversLicence" formControlName="driversLicence" id="driversLicence" ng-checked="false">Drivers Licence</ion-toggle>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <br>

    <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="jobModel.sex" formControlName="sex" id="sex">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Male</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="1"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Female</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="2"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <br>
    <ion-buttons>
      <button ion-button class="form-button-text" type="submit" [disabled]="!jobdetailsForm.valid" block round>Next</button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </form>

<div class="footer">
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <p class="small-text-search">Please do not post any personally identifiable information, or sensitive information such as bank details and ID numbers, or any information you don’t want in the hands of others.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: so button action is not working..can you check syntax errors and what is console output

Comment: Thanks. There are no errors in the console. I cannot click the button, because as soon as I scroll down to the button, it automatically scrolls up to the text area, and the button is off the screen.

Comment: can you show us your code in a plunker or a github repo..so it will be easy to debug for us..

Comment: I have added the code above